# How do I parse a string representing a recursive data structure using Perl regular expressions?

Tags: regex, perl, tree

I wonder what methods are in Perl for traversing a recursive structure (e.g. binary tree)
which is given as a string.

More concretely:

Here is a tree, for simplicity is parse tree and very short.
imagine it is string without fancy tabbing and spaces.

```
tree(Sentence, 
  tree(NounPhrase,
    leaf(Determiner, "a"),
    leaf(Noun, "man", "singular")
  ), 
  tree(VerbPhrase,
    leaf(Verb, "walks", "present", "3rd person")
  )
)
```

Now I want to access two direct child nodes of the root,
but I cannot do this with regular expressions simply.

```
m/tree \( \w+ , (group1) , (group2) \) /x
```

I would like to capture group1 and group2 correctly,
i.e. group1 and group2 having even number of opening and closing parentheses.

**It seems quite complicated task and wonder what is the common/simplest solution to it?**

For example, prolog will easily digest this task.

Comment: Is creating an equivalent data structure from the string an option for you? This might pay off quickly. In either case, regular expressions are not good enough. You have to specify a (recursive) grammar.

Comment: "but I cannot do this with regular expressions simply." ... and neither can anyone else.

Comment: Step 1: make a [lexer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analysis). Step 2: make a [parser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Parser).

Answer (score 2):

I would try by creating 2 functions: `sub tree{}` and `sub leaf{}`

each of them would return a tagged term as a string, for example `leaf(Determiner, "a")` would return `<Determiner>a</Determiner>`

then simply execute the file you want to process. The output would be a DOM like structure which you can parse with any DOM parser like [`XML::DOM`](http://search.cpan.org/~tjmather/XML-DOM-1.44/lib/XML/DOM.pm) for example

Answer (score 0):

Ok, thanks, so the answer is 
"Simply, it is not possible only with RegEx".

Comment: It's not possible with regular expressions like defined in computer science, but it is certainly possible with Perl regular expressions. You can even parse JSON with a single RegExp: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=995856. I doubt that you would classify that as a "simple solution", though ;-)

Comment: That's wrong. There exists a short and elegant albeit conceptually complex regex that can solve this problem. (I have posted it as a distinct answer.) A more correct way of putting this would be that using regular expressions is not the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many children to expect, which your example regex suggests, then it is fairly easy, and something like this will be enough:

```
my @children = m{ tree\(  \w+?, ( (?:tree|leaf)\(.+\) ), ( (?:tree|leaf)\(.+\) ) \) }x;
```

If you don't, which seems more likely, then it is indeed not simple, but it is possible. In [his book on regular expressions](http://regex.info/book.html), Jeffrey Friedl suggests using what he calls the *dynamic regex construct* to build a recursive pattern in order to match nested pairs.

```
# first, strip your string
s{ ^ tree\( \w+ , (.+) \) $ }{$1}x;

# then, define the recursive pattern to match paired parentheses
my $recursion;
$recursion = qr{ (?> [^()]+ | \( (??{ $recursion }) \) )* }x;

# finally, match!
my @children = m{ ( (?: tree | leaf ) \( $recursion \) ) ,?}gx;
```

In perlre, this is called *[postponed regular subexpression](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#%28??%7B-code-%7D%29)*, <del>and is noted as an experimental feature</del>.